# CountDown timer RxJava

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Делаю операцию авторизации при помощи RxJava. Но хочу чтобы по истечению 10 минут выполнилась операция разлогирования. Как можно установить таймер и выполнить эту операцию при помощи RxJava? Нашёл [доки](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timer.html) но получается мне нужно будет её вызывать сразу же после авторизации, что мне не очень нравится.

Comment: Я думаю это не та задача где стоит использовать RxJava. Я бы попробовал использовать ```AlarmManager```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй посмотреть в сторону оператора interval.

Реализуется следующим образом:

```
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
Observable.interval(UPDATE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap(/** Здесь отправляешь запрос на разлогин */.retry().subscribeOn(scheduler))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(/** Подписываешься и выполняешь необходимые действия после разлогина */);
```

UPDATE_TIMEOUT - временной интервал. После разлогина можешь с помощью какой-нибудь булевской переменной проверять, разлогинен или нет, чтобы заново не проверять.